# Cisco ASA 5505 can't talk to anything on Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

So I have a Cisco ASA 5505 Setup with 2 Site-to-Site VPN's and a Remote Access VPN, now anything connected (Hardwired, S2S VPN or RA VPN) can all talk to each other without a problem.

The problem comes is via the one of the S2S VPN's I have an Active Directory setup, I'm trying to change the RA VPN to use the LDAP Login provided by this AS DS but it appears the ASA its self can't talk via the S2S VPN.

So AD DS Server is on IP `10.1.18.109`

(Network ranges run by the ASA)

```
ASA is on 10.101.0.1/255.255.0.0
In Office (so Hardwired into ASA) is on 10.101.1.0/255.255.0.0
RA VPN is on 10.101.2.0/255.255.0.0
```

(Network ranged via S2S VPNs)

```
S2S VPN Ireland is on 10.2.0.0/255.255.0.0
S2S VPN London is on 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

So I need the ASA to talk to 10.1.18.109 currently it can't talk to it in anyway LDAP just connection times out, and ping just fails.

*What I have tried*

All NAT rules for the VPN have the Route Lookup turned on checked ACL and it should be allowed

*How I'm testing*

I have been testing ping via both VLANs inside `ping inside 10.1.18.109` and outside `ping outside 10.1.18.109`

*What I think is wrong*

I'm not the best so I think it's something to do with the ASA running on a 10.101.0.1 IP address and it not being allowed to access the VPNs

The current config.

```
 : Saved
    :
    ASA Version 9.1(1) 
    !
    hostname ciscoasa
    domain-name fabrikam.ltd
    enable password xxxxxxxxxxxxxx encrypted
    passwd xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx encrypted
    names
    ip local pool OutOfOfficePool 10.101.2.1-10.101.2.254 mask 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface Ethernet0/0
     switchport access vlan 2
    !
    interface Ethernet0/1
    !
    interface Ethernet0/2
    !
    interface Ethernet0/3
    !
    interface Ethernet0/4
    !
    interface Ethernet0/5
    !
    interface Ethernet0/6
    !
    interface Ethernet0/7
    !
    interface Vlan1
     nameif inside
     security-level 100
     ip address 10.101.0.1 255.255.0.0 
    !
    interface Vlan2
     nameif outside
     security-level 0
     ip address y.y.y.y 255.255.255.248 
    !
    ftp mode passive
    dns domain-lookup inside
    dns domain-lookup outside
    dns server-group DefaultDNS
     name-server 10.1.18.109
     domain-name fabrikam.ltd
    same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
    object network obj_any
     subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
    object network inside
     subnet 10.101.0.0 255.255.0.0
    object network inside-subnet
     subnet 10.101.0.0 255.255.0.0
    object network obj-SrcNet
     subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
    object network obj-amzn-lon
     subnet 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0
    object network obj-amzn-ire
     subnet 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0
    object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.101.2.0_24
     subnet 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0
    object network inoffice
     subnet 10.101.1.0 255.255.255.0
    object network outoffice
     subnet 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0
    object network 10.X.X.X
     range 10.2.0.0 10.2.255.255
    access-list outside_acl extended permit ip host x.x.x.x host y.y.y.y 
    access-list outside_acl extended permit ip host v.v.v.v host y.y.y.y 
    access-list outside_acl extended permit ip host m.m.m.m host y.y.y.y 
    access-list outside_acl extended permit ip host z.z.z.z host y.y.y.y 
    access-list acl-amzn-lon extended permit ip any 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list IRELAND-135 extended permit ip host m.m.m.m host y.y.y.y 
    access-list IRELAND-159 extended permit ip host z.z.z.z host y.y.y.y 
    access-list IRELAND-LOCAL extended permit ip any4 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip host x.x.x.x host y.y.y.y 
    access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip host v.v.v.v host y.y.y.y 
    access-list acl-amzn extended permit ip any4 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list amzn-filter extended permit ip 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.101.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list ireland-filter extended permit ip 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.101.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list outside_cryptomap_2 extended permit ip any4 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list outside_cryptomap_2 extended permit ip any 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list outside_cryptomap_3 extended permit ip any 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list outside_cryptomap_1 extended permit ip any 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list tcp_bypass extended permit tcp 10.101.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0 
    access-list tcp_bypass extended permit tcp 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0 
    access-list tcp_bypass extended permit tcp 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list tcp_bypass extended permit tcp 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0 
    access-list tcp_bypass extended permit tcp 10.101.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0 
    access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip any any 
    access-list acl-outside extended permit icmp any any echo 
    access-list acl-inside extended permit icmp any any echo 
    access-list global_mpc extended permit ip any any 
    pager lines 24
    logging enable
    logging asdm informational
    mtu inside 1500
    mtu outside 1500
    icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
    icmp permit any outside
    no asdm history enable
    arp timeout 14400
    no arp permit-nonconnected
    nat (inside,outside) source static obj-SrcNet obj-SrcNet destination static obj-amzn-ire obj-amzn-ire route-lookup
    nat (inside,outside) source static obj-SrcNet obj-SrcNet destination static obj-amzn-lon obj-amzn-lon route-lookup
    nat (inside,outside) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.101.2.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.101.2.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
    !
    object network obj_any
     nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
    object network inside-subnet
     nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
    !
    nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
    access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
    route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 109.239.111.1 1
    timeout xlate 3:00:00
    timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
    timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
    timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
    timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
    timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
    timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
    timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
    dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
    aaa-server LDAP_SRV_GRP protocol ldap
    aaa-server LDAP_SRV_GRP (outside) host 10.1.18.109
     ldap-base-dn dc=fabrikam, dc=ltd
     ldap-scope subtree
     ldap-naming-attribute sAMAccountName
     ldap-login-password *****
     ldap-login-dn cn=Administrator, cn=Users, dc=fabrikam, dc=ltd
     server-type microsoft
    user-identity default-domain LOCAL
    http server enable
    http 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 inside
    no snmp-server location
    no snmp-server contact
    snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
    sysopt connection tcpmss 1379
    sla monitor 1
     type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 10.1.0.1 interface outside
     frequency 5
    sla monitor schedule 1 life forever start-time now
    sla monitor 2
     type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 10.2.0.1 interface outside
     frequency 5
    sla monitor schedule 2 life forever start-time now
    sla monitor 5
     type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 8.8.8.8 interface outside
     frequency 5
    sla monitor schedule 5 life forever start-time now
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn-lon esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn-ire esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transfrom-amzn esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transfrom-amzn1 esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn1 esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-ireland esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA1_TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA1_TRANS mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set APPLE_CLIENT esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
    crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set APPLE_CLIENT mode transport
    crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
     protocol esp encryption des
     protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
    crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
     protocol esp encryption 3des
     protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
    crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
     protocol esp encryption aes
     protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
    crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
     protocol esp encryption aes-192
     protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
    crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
     protocol esp encryption aes-256
     protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
    crypto ipsec security-association replay window-size 128
    crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
    crypto ipsec df-bit clear-df outside
    crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set pfs group1
    crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-DES-SHA ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS
    crypto dynamic-map DYN_OUTSIDE 10000 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA1_TRANS
    crypto dynamic-map DYN_OUTSIDE 10000 set reverse-route
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 1 match address acl-amzn-lon
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 1 set pfs 
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 1 set peer x.x.x.x v.v.v.v 
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn-lon
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 2 match address outside_cryptomap_2
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 2 set pfs 
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 2 set peer m.m.m.m z.z.z.z 
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 2 set ikev1 transform-set transform-ireland
    crypto map amazon_lon_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 match address outside_cryptomap_1
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 set pfs 
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 set peer x.x.x.x v.v.v.v 
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 set ikev1 transform-set transfrom-amzn
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 1 set reverse-route
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 2 match address outside_cryptomap_3
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 2 set pfs 
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 2 set peer m.m.m.m z.z.z.z 
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 2 set ikev1 transform-set transform-ireland
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 2 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 2 set reverse-route
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE 10000 ipsec-isakmp dynamic DYN_OUTSIDE
    crypto map MAP_OUTSIDE interface outside
    crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
     crl configure
    crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
     enrollment self
     subject-name CN=ciscoasa
     keypair OutOfOfficeKeyPair
     proxy-ldc-issuer
     crl configure
    crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint1
     enrollment terminal
     subject-name CN=leeds.internal.fabrikam.ltd,O=fabrikam Limited,C=UK
     keypair OutOfOfficeKeyPair
     crl configure
    crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint2
     enrollment terminal
     crl configure
    crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint3
     enrollment terminal
     no validation-usage
     crl configure
    crypto ca trustpool policy
    crypto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
     certificate ca * removed*
      quit
    crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
     certificate 7f301c5c *removed*

      quit
    crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint3
     certificate ca *removed*
      quit
    crypto isakmp identity address 
    crypto ikev2 policy 1
     encryption aes-256
     integrity sha
     group 5 2
     prf sha
     lifetime seconds 86400
    crypto ikev2 policy 10
     encryption aes-192
     integrity sha
     group 5 2
     prf sha
     lifetime seconds 86400
    crypto ikev2 policy 20
     encryption aes
     integrity sha
     group 5 2
     prf sha
     lifetime seconds 86400
    crypto ikev2 policy 30
     encryption 3des
     integrity sha
     group 5 2
     prf sha
     lifetime seconds 86400
    crypto ikev2 policy 40
     encryption des
     integrity sha
     group 5 2
     prf sha
     lifetime seconds 86400
    crypto ikev1 enable outside
    crypto ikev1 policy 201
     authentication pre-share
     encryption aes
     hash sha
     group 2
     lifetime 28800
    crypto ikev1 policy 1000
     authentication pre-share
     encryption aes-256
     hash sha
     group 2
     lifetime 86400
    crypto ikev1 policy 2000
     authentication pre-share
     encryption 3des
     hash sha
     group 2
     lifetime 86400
    crypto ikev1 policy 3000
     authentication pre-share
     encryption aes
     hash sha
     group 2
     lifetime 86400
    telnet timeout 5
    ssh timeout 5
    console timeout 0

    dhcpd domain leeds.internal.fabrikam.ltd
    dhcpd auto_config outside
    dhcpd option 3 ip 10.101.0.1 y.y.y.y
    dhcpd option 6 ip 10.1.13.58 8.8.8.8
    !
    dhcpd address 10.101.1.1-10.101.1.254 inside
    dhcpd domain leeds.internal.fabrikam.ltd interface inside
    dhcpd option 3 ip 10.101.0.1 interface inside
    dhcpd option 6 ip 10.1.13.58 8.8.8.8 interface inside
    dhcpd enable inside
    !
    threat-detection basic-threat
    threat-detection statistics access-list
    no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
    webvpn
     enable outside
    group-policy DefaultRAGroup internal
    group-policy DefaultRAGroup attributes
     dns-server value 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
     vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec 
     default-domain value leeds.internal.fabrikam.ltd
    group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
    group-policy OutOfOffice internal
    group-policy OutOfOffice attributes
     dns-server value 10.1.18.109 1.1.1.1
     vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 l2tp-ipsec 
     default-domain value leeds.internal.fabrikam.ltd
    group-policy ireland-filter internal
    group-policy ireland-filter attributes
     vpn-filter value ireland-filter
     vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 
    group-policy filter1 internal
    group-policy filter1 attributes
     vpn-filter value amzn-filter
     vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 
    group-policy filter internal
    group-policy filter attributes
     vpn-filter value acl-amzn
    username user1 password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx nt-encrypted
    username user1 attributes
     vpn-group-policy OutOfOffice
     vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 l2tp-ipsec 
     service-type remote-access 
    tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
     address-pool OutOfOfficePool
     default-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
    tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
    tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
     authentication pap
     authentication ms-chap-v2
    tunnel-group x.x.x.x type ipsec-l2l
    tunnel-group x.x.x.x general-attributes
     default-group-policy filter1
    tunnel-group x.x.x.x ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
     isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10
    tunnel-group v.v.v.v type ipsec-l2l
    tunnel-group v.v.v.v general-attributes
     default-group-policy filter1
    tunnel-group v.v.v.v ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
     isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10
    tunnel-group IRELAND-135 type ipsec-l2l
    tunnel-group IRELAND-135 general-attributes
     default-group-policy ireland-filter
    tunnel-group IRELAND-135 ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
     isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10
    tunnel-group IRELAND-159 type ipsec-l2l
    tunnel-group IRELAND-159 general-attributes
     default-group-policy ireland-filter
    tunnel-group IRELAND-159 ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
     isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10
    tunnel-group OutOfOffice type remote-access
    tunnel-group OutOfOffice general-attributes
     address-pool OutOfOfficePool
     authentication-server-group LDAP_SRV_GRP LOCAL
     default-group-policy OutOfOffice
    tunnel-group OutOfOffice ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
     ikev1 trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0
    tunnel-group OutOfOffice ppp-attributes
     authentication ms-chap-v2
    tunnel-group m.m.m.m type ipsec-l2l
    tunnel-group m.m.m.m general-attributes
     default-group-policy ireland-filter
    tunnel-group m.m.m.m ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
    tunnel-group z.z.z.z type ipsec-l2l
    tunnel-group z.z.z.z general-attributes
     default-group-policy ireland-filter
    tunnel-group z.z.z.z ipsec-attributes
     ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
    !
    class-map inspection_default
     match access-list global_mpc
     match default-inspection-traffic
    class-map tcp_bypass
     match access-list tcp_bypass
    !
    !
    policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
     parameters
      message-length maximum client auto
      message-length maximum 512
    policy-map global_policy
     class inspection_default
      inspect dns preset_dns_map 
      inspect ftp 
      inspect h323 h225 
      inspect h323 ras 
      inspect rsh 
      inspect rtsp 
      inspect esmtp 
      inspect sqlnet 
      inspect skinny  
      inspect sunrpc 
      inspect xdmcp 
      inspect sip  
      inspect netbios 
      inspect tftp 
      inspect ip-options 
      inspect icmp 
    policy-map tcp_bypass_policy
     class tcp_bypass
      set connection advanced-options tcp-state-bypass
    !
    service-policy global_policy global
    service-policy tcp_bypass_policy interface inside
    prompt hostname context 
    no call-home reporting anonymous
    : end
```

I have even tried port 80 TCP pings to no avail,

On the outside interface

```
Sending 5 TCP SYN requests to 10.1.18.109 port 80
from 109.239.111.4, timeout is 2 seconds:
?????
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

On the inside interface

```
Sending 5 TCP SYN requests to 10.1.18.109 port 80
from 109.239.111.4, timeout is 2 seconds:
?????
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

The VPC flow logs at Amazon AWS don't show any attempted connection to that IP address

My NAT Rules easily visible, 
[image: ADSM NAT Rules output]

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm happy to help you with this.  Are you still looking for advice with this problem?

Comment: Hi @RobPearson yeah i am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you will need in a situation like this is the `management-access <interface-name>` global command, where "< interface-name >" is the inside interface nameif. The ASA will not put its own traffic into a VPN tunnel by default, so this command grants that behavior.  This command will also allow you to SSH to the firewall from the other side of the tunnel, as well.

In order for this to work properly, the NAT statement that covers the firewall's subnet needs to have the `route-lookup` keyword added, which it sounds like yours does already.

Comment: Thanks for this it does sound like what I need but unfortunately, the command does not work on my ASA via ASDM - I will try directly on the hardware tomorrow once im back on site.

Comment: Ok so I have found this `management-interface` is a replacement for the old command `management-access` so if you could update to say management-interface or management-access <iface-name> I will happily accept it

Comment: My appologies, I did make an error telling you `management-interface` rather than `management-access`.  I was on my phone... not thinking.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me point out the general "hint" what to check based on your description. Hopefully it will help even it is not directly "copy&paste" solution. I am sorry in advance for not going through the configuration you have provided... :-)

### NAT - source address / interface for this LDAP traffic

Usually the NAT is set up against the network so the traffic going through (not originated directly on ASA) is "matched" to the rule to "exclude" the default NAT (MASQUERADE) or to set up specific NAT required for the traffic. Try to catch small amount of the relevant traffic and make focus on source IP of the packet. It is possible that the source is not what you expect...

In case you don't handle it explicitly already the relevant interface (even for ipsec tunnel) is outside. In that case the IP is not the IP you expect/set up in the configuration for the "ipsec tunnel" communication (crypto map, NAT, firewall rules,...) and the result is that this communication is just not work even from any other "internal" device it is working without issue. In that case the explicit NAT rule for this traffic would help to fit the communication to the tunnel (the first option which came to my mind).

Comment: I'm sorry you confused me but I tried adding a specific nat rule of Source 10.101.0.0/24 to the destination of S2S VPN and it made no difference.

Comment: In case I am pointing the correct stuff for your issue the source IP for the traffic is not ``10.101.0.1`` what you probably expect (it would be properly covered by the setting you have done) but ``y.y.y.y`` - interface Vlan2 in your setting. Your site2site tunnel setting don't expect y.y.y.y as source address so it would not fit the tunnel "requirements" and it is not send out via tunnel... In other words the traffic is not originated via Vlan1 but Vlan2 ;-). The rule what may help would be sNAT for source y.y.y.y and destination 10...(other side of tunnel) to change source IP for 10.101.0.1.

Comment: Oh I have tried ping via both VLANs, using `ping outside 10.1.18.109` and `ping inside 10.1.18.109` updated my Question to show the Nat rules in UI form.

Comment: Using outside it is not matching traffic for VPN tunnel and for inside ASA cannot handle this kind of traffic as the destination is simply not on inside interface but on outside one. ASA is quite strictly differentiating it. Try to set NAT rule that both source and destination interface will be outside and in case source is outside interface IP and destination will be remote `10.1.0.0/16` to set up source IP explicitly local one `10.101.0.1` (if not working try some local not used one e.g. `10.101.6.66`). **Try to catch the traffic on other side to see if it is at least going one direction!**

Comment: I tried that It won't let me do it because the IP is the IP of the inside interface @Kamil J

Comment: hmm ok and did you tried the part **if not working try some local not used one e.g. 10.101.6.66** ?

Comment: If i tried any none existant IP the same thing happens as it sending the external IP